# Creating a "login.events.pre" hook in liferay

Tags: authentication, hook, liferay, liferay-6

I'm very new to liferay and am creating a hook on the login.events.pre event. My users will be signing in to the website by using their phone number, so I have to do some validations on the status of their phone line before letting liferay create a session for the user. I've already created the portlet and am able to execute some java code before letting liferay take care of the login validation, but I'm not sure how to stop the whole process if my validation fails. In other words, if I find out that the users phone line is suspended, I don't want liferay to allow them to sign in, even if the right login info has been provided by the user. Is it possible to do this in the login.events.pre event in liferay?

Comment: could you please share your code, I need to check the login id is screen name or email id, then set the auth_type value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can invalidate the `Session` and redirect it to some customized error page in your `hook`.

Below piece of code might be helpful.

```
//Below code to get the current session
HttpSession session = null;
session=request.getSession(false);

//Below code to invalidate the session and to redirect to your customized error page
session.invalidate();
response.sendRedirect("/errorPage.html");
```